# Conditionals in WHEREs or JOINs?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have the following query:

```
SELECT occurs.*, events.*
FROM occurs
    INNER JOIN events ON (events.event_id = occurs.event_id)
WHERE event.event_state = 'visible'
```

Another way to do the same query and get the same results would be:

```
SELECT occurs.*, events.*
FROM occurs
    INNER JOIN events ON (events.event_id = occurs.event_id
        AND event.event_state = 'visible')
```

My question. Is there a real difference? Is one way faster than the other? Why would I choose one way over the other?

Comment: do an execution plan on both queries if there are difference the database will show you!

Comment: 2nd one is faster. Especially if you have `event.event_state` indexed

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` before each query.  It'll show you the how the query optimizer is running it and the index(es) being used.  P.S. I'm pretty sure these are identical.

Comment: Related: [INNER JOIN ON vs. WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an `INNER JOIN`, there's no conceptual difference between putting a condition in `ON` and in `WHERE`. It's a common practice to use `ON` for conditions that connect a key in one table to a foreign key in another table, such as your `event_id`, so that other people maintaining your code can see how the tables relate.

If you suspect that your database engine is mis-optimizing a query plan, you can try it both ways. Make sure to time the query several times to isolate the effect of caching, and make sure to run `ANALYZE TABLE occurs` and `ANALYZE TABLE events` to provide more info to the optimizer about the distribution of keys. If you do find a difference, have the database engine `EXPLAIN` the query plans it generates. If there's a gross mis-optimization, you can create an Oracle account and file a feature request against MySQL to optimize a particular query better.

But for a `LEFT JOIN`, there's a big difference. A `LEFT JOIN` is often used to add details from a separate table if the details exist or return the rows without details if they do not. This query will return result rows with `NULL` values for `b.*` if no row of `b` matches both conditions:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
ON (condition_one
    AND condition_two)
WHERE condition_three
```

Whereas this one will completely omit results that do not match `condition_two`:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON some_condition
WHERE condition_two
  AND condition_three
```

<sub>Code in this answer is dual licensed: [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) or the [MIT License as published by OSI](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).</sub>